# How to make an empty shape in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

i wanted to draw a circle in pygame that is empty, i mean you should see behind surface through it.

i wrote a code that find all the colored pixels in a surface and empty their coordinates in the other surface.

```py
def draw_empty(surf1, surf2, pos):
    """makes surf2 pixels empty on surf1"""
    pixobj2 = pygame.PixelArray(surf2)
    empty = []
    for x in range(len(pixobj2)):
        for y in range(len(pixobj2[x])):
            if pixobj2[x][y]!=0:
                empty.append((x,y))
    del pixobj2
    pixobj1 = pygame.PixelArray(surf1)
    for pix in empty:
        pixobj1[pix[0]+pos[0]][pix[1]+pos[1]] = 0
    del pixobj1
window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
white_surf = pygame.surface.Surface((600, 600))
white_surf.fill((255, 255, 255))
circle_surf = pygame.surface.Surface((50, 50))
pygame.draw.circle(circle_surf, (1, 1, 1), circle_surf.get_rect().center, 25)
pic = pygame.image.load('pic.png')
pic = pygame.transform.scale(pic, (600, 600))
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    draw_empty(white_surf, circle_surf, (200, 200))
    window.blit(pic, (0, 0))
    window.blit(white_surf, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
```

i expected to see background picture through that circle but the circle i just black, is this even possible to do that? can somebody help me with this?

P.S. 
by empty, i mean like a hole in my front surface

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `draw()` function:

```
pygame.draw.circle(Surface, color, pos, radius, width=0)
```

`width` represents the size of the circumference curve. When it is 0, the circle is solid. If you set it to 1, the edge will be only one pixel wide (an empty circle).

edit: to draw a circle with a sprite, you can use this code<sup>†</sup>:

```
import pygame
import pygame.gfxdraw

IMG = pygame.Surface((30, 30), pygame.SRCALPHA)
pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(IMG, 15, 15, 14, (0, 255, 0))
pygame.gfxdraw.filled_circle(IMG, 15, 15, 14, (0, 255, 0))

class img(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = IMG
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(150, 200))
```

---

<sup>†</sup>Credit for code goes to [dunker_wanderer](https://www.reddit.com/user/dunkler_wanderer/)

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the shape the same way you would if it had a color or surface image, and then just set the fill to a transparent color using:

```
empty = (255,255,255,0) 
surface.fill(empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to figure out how to add this to your code without breaking it, or rewrite it but, first you will need to make a set with three numbers

white = (255, 255, 255)

next use the function

pygame.draw.rect(canvas_name, set_name, (100, 100, 100, 100))

last use
pygame.display.flip()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

#Initializes pygame import pygame, random, sys, time, math pygame.init()

```
#Creates screen screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 350)) pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

#Initializes screen running = True while running:   pass    
#Colors screen  white = (255, 255, 255)     screen.fill(white)

#Draws rectangle    num1 = random.randrange(0, 255)     num2 = random.randrange(0, 255)     num3 = random.randrange(0, 255)
            color = (num1, num2, num3)  pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(100, 100, 60, 60), )

    pygame.display.flip()
    #Made by and only by the kid genius Nathan
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).